# how to open whatsapp or whatsapp business with intent android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

I'm using this code, and it opens WhatsApp, but it doesn't allow me to open WhatsApp business, is there any way to verify which WhatsApp the user has installed?

```
String contact = phone;
Double amount_total = pac_val_amo + del_fac_amo;
String total = "S/. " + String.format("%.2f", amount_total);
String message = "Su pedido de " + store + " ha llegado, su pago total es de S/. " + total;
String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + contact + "&text=" + message;
try {
    PackageManager pm = getContext().getPackageManager();
    pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
           Toast.makeText(getContext(), "WhatsApp is not installed on this Device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can open whatsapp business by using its package name ***com.whatsapp.w4b***

Just do an if else check between com.whatsapp and com.whatsapp.w4b before starting the intent